# Inside an inner join Select based on input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one big query that is part of a stored procedure and it was working as expected. Now I've introduced input parameters and want to modify the query based on them. The problem that I have is that inside the inner join I want to `SELECT` based on the input parameter value, but this ends up in syntax error -> `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.`

```sql
declare @AreasIds nvarchar(max) = '185,186,194,195,201,202,205,492,483'

select i.Id, i.Title, 
a.Areas,
from tblIncidents as i
inner join
(
    IF @AreasIds is not null and @AreaIds != ''
        select i.Id,STRING_AGG(ar.Title,';') as Areas
        from tblIncident i
        left join
        (
            select a.Id, a.Title, ia.Type, ia.GlobalObjectId
            from tblItemArea as ia
            inner join tblArea a on ia.AreaId = a.Id
            where ia.Type = 100 and a.Archived != 'true' and a.IsDeleted != 'true' and a.Id in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AreaIds, ','))
        ) as ar on ar.GlobalObjectId = i.Id
        group by i.Id
        having STRING_AGG(ar.Title,';') is not null
    ELSE
        select i.Id,STRING_AGG(ar.Title,';') as Areas
        from tblIncident i
        left join
        (
            select a.Id, a.Title, ia.Type, ia.GlobalObjectId
            from tblItemArea as ia
            inner join tblArea a on ia.AreaId = a.Id
            where ia.Type = 100 and a.Archived != 'true' and a.IsDeleted != 'true'
        ) as ar on ar.GlobalObjectId = i.Id
        group by i.Id
) a on i.Id = a.Id
where i.MyCustomFilter = 216 and i.Archived != 'true' and i.IsDeleted != 'true'
```

The logic is return all `Incidents` if not input query parameter is passed or filter the data to show only incidents with the given `AreaIds`.

How should I modify the query in order for it to run?

Comment: I suspect you have a  XY problem

Comment: *"I receive syntax errors:"* You have an `IF...ELSE` inside your statements; that isn't allowed. `IF...ELSE` is a control flow operation; you can't control the flow of the statements run mid-way through a statement.

Comment: Edited based on the XY, @Larnu thanks, so what is the correct approach here?

Comment: Like you want an `OR`. Perhaps `A.ID IN ({Split}) OR @AreasIds IS NULL`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, thank you! I've got a bit rusty with SQL but now will quickly get back to it as the project requires. If you want you can add an answer. I've fixed it by removing if else leaving one query inside the `inner` join with a big `where` clause -> `where (ia.Type = 100 and a.Archived != 'true' and a.IsDeleted != 'true') and ((@AreasIds is null or @AreasIds = '') or a.Id in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AreasIds, ',')))` and modifying `having` -> `having @AreasIds is null or @AreasIds = '' or STRING_AGG(ar.Title,';') is not null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a control-of-flow statement, not an expression, and you cannot place one statement inside another.

You could just use some simple `or` logic:

```sql
declare @AreasIds nvarchar(max) = '185,186,194,195,201,202,205,492,483'

select
  i.Id,
  i.Title, 
  a.Areas,
from tblIncidents as i
inner join
(
        select i.Id,STRING_AGG(ar.Title, ';') as Areas
        from tblIncident i
        left join
        (
            select a.Id, a.Title, ia.Type, ia.GlobalObjectId
            from tblItemArea as ia
            inner join tblArea a on ia.AreaId = a.Id
            where ia.Type = 100
              and a.Archived != 'true'
              and a.IsDeleted != 'true'
              and (
                @AreasIds is null or @AreaIds = ''
                or a.Id in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@AreaIds, ','))
              )
        ) as ar on ar.GlobalObjectId = i.Id
        group by i.Id
        having @AreasIds is null or @AreaIds = ''
            or STRING_AGG(ar.Title, ';') is not null
) a on i.Id = a.Id
where i.MyCustomFilter = 216
  and i.Archived != 'true'
  and i.IsDeleted != 'true';
```

But your query should probably be rewritten anyway.

- Use a table variable or Table Value Parameter to store multiple IDs.
- True/false columns should be of type `bit`, and use `=` not `!=` where possible.

```sql
declare @AreasIds table (id int PRIMARY KEY);
insert @AreaIds (id) values
(185),
(186),
(194),
(195),
(201),
(202),
(205),
(492),
(483);

declare @withAreaIds bit = 1;

select
  i.Id,
  i.Title, 
  a.Areas,
from tblIncidents as i
inner join
(
    select
      i.Id,
      STRING_AGG(ar.Title, ';') as Areas
    from tblIncident i
    left join
    (
        select
          a.Title,
          ia.GlobalObjectId
        from tblItemArea as ia
        inner join tblArea a on ia.AreaId = a.Id
        where ia.Type = 100
          and a.Archived = 0
          and a.IsDeleted = 0
          and (
              @withAreasIds = 0
              or a.Id in (SELECT id FROM @AreaIds)
              )
     ) as ar on ar.GlobalObjectId = i.Id
     group by i.Id
     having @withAreasIds = 0
            or STRING_AGG(ar.Title, ';') is not null
) a on i.Id = a.Id
where i.MyCustomFilter = 216
  and i.Archived = 0
  and i.IsDeleted = 0;
```

Comment: yes, this did the trick, thanks